# i have a weird baritone voice and why is my range so limited

Tags: voice

I am a 19 years old I have recently started to sing about two years ago and I just want to know why I have such a limited range I’m a baritone but I don’t fit the basic standard for it, my range is a G2-G4# with my falsetto reaching A5, in my choir we have tenors who can sing higher and lower than me, so I just feel obsolete you know, like why is my voice so limited, and also I have such a unique sounding voice that my range and tone of voice barley sound good on any songs and I just find it confusing and just kinda disappointing and discouraging. I sit there a listen to all these new heights being accomplished and I can’t hit an A4 or an F2 in my chest voice.

Comment: We all have different ranges, and have to just get on with them. Like how tall we are, what shoe size we take, how clever we are, etc. We try to make the best of what we've been given!

Comment: If you’ve only been singing for two years and specially if you aren’t taking singing lessons from an experienced voice teacher, then that’s why your range isn’t bigger. Also two octaves is a good range. That’s much bigger than mine. If I’m fully warmed up I’m like A2 - E4. You can be happy with your range.

Comment: Nineteen is very young for a male singer.  Your voice will continue to mature for a few years yet.  But chest voice A4 is definitely tenor territory.  If you're truly a baritone, which G2 suggests you are, this is unlikely ever to be comfortable.  Learn to use the voice that you have rather than trying to turn it into something that it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

You have got a vocal range of over two full octaves there. This is absolutely not a limited range, especially considering you are 19 and have been singing only for two years. Technique will extend your voice in both directions, so if you take this seriously this will not be the end for you. Trust me, I’ve been working with church choirs where some singers would have a range of not even an octave. Two octaves is not at all a bad vocal range!

Also some tenors might be able to produce quite low notes, and some basses might produce quite high notes, but still there is a different in effort, tone, dynamic expressiveness and tiring of the voice. So there is a place for each voice type. Furthermore a choir is not a bunch of soloists taking single roles, so no singer in a choir is obsolete just because there are other singers who have larger vocal ranges.